# How to configure login when using multiple servers running a distributed service (HAProxy, Apache, Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached, distributed, haproxy

I have 3 servers running a website. I now need to implement login system and I am having problems with it as user gets a different behavior (logged in or logged out) depending on the server it gets connected to.

I am using Memcache for session store in Rails - 
   config.action_controller.session_store = :mem_cache_store

ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore.new("server1","server2","server3")

I thought the second line will either keep caches in sync or something like that ...

Each server has its own db with 1 master, 2 slaves. I have tried going the route of doing sessions in sql store but that really hurts sql servers and replication load becomes really heavy.

Is there an easy way to say, use this Memcache for all session store on all 3 servers?

Will that solve my problem?

I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used memcached to store sessions before ( I feel like redis is a better solution ), but I think as long as you have the 
`ActiveSupport::Cache::MemCacheStore.new("server1","server2","server3")`
line on each of your application servers, your sessions should stay synced up.

I've had a lot of success with just using regular cookie sessions using the same setup you've described.